# storing global variables in the window object Javascript

Tags: global-variables

In my application I have multiple variables that need to be accessed globally from the different functions of my script:

```
var a=1,b=2,c, ...;
```

Where "c" undefined at the beginning and takes value produced by some of the functions during scripts execution.

In order to declare them from within my "main" function I'm trying to use window object:

```
window.a=1;
window.b=2;
window.c;
```

This works, however I'm not sure if such approach is correct.
And is there is a way to avoid creation multiple window objects for each variable and combine them into more compact structure? Something like:

```
window.a=1,.b=2,.c;//---of course-this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asking this question today too. It used to be the way when I last wrote javascript (mid-90s) and still seems to be the case [see this resource](https://javascript.info/global-object)